# Mostrar las rooms en socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io, websocket

Soy nuevo en socket.io y quisiera saber como listar las room que se crean en socket.io.

Creo una room por cada usuario, lo que deseo es que el Administrador pueda ver las rooms creadas, poder unirse a alguna y tener un chat privado.

Con el siguiente código creo las rooms.

**Cliente**

```
//Enviar Mensaje al servidor
enviar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Enviando Datos al Servidor
    socket.emit('asistenciaCliente', {
        usuario: usuario.value,
        mensaje: mensaje.value
    });

});

socket.on('asistenciaServidor', function(datos) {
    // console.log(datos);
    salida.innerHTML +=
        `<p>
        <strong>${datos.usuario}:</strong> ${datos.mensaje}
    </p>`;
    salida.scrollIntoView(false); //Mostrar Ultimos Mensajes en Pantalla de forma automatica
});
```

**Servidor**

```
 //Escuchando el evento del Cliente Mensaje
    socket.on('asistenciaCliente', (datos) => {
      console.log(datos);

      socket.join(datos.usuario);
      io.sockets.to(datos.usuario).emit('asistenciaServidor', datos);
    });

    socket.on('asistenciaAdmin', (datos) => {
      console.log(datos);

      socket.join(datos.usuario);//Room por cada Usuario
      io.sockets.to(datos.usuario).emit('asistenciaServidor', datos);
      //io.sockets.emit('asistenciaServidor', datos);//Enviando datos al Administrador
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Espero con este segmento de código puedas tener una idea mas clara de como lograr tu objetivo, mantente informado si logras tu cometido.

```
function lstRooms() {
    var listRooms= io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
    if (rooms) {
        for (var room in rooms) {
            listRooms.push(room);
        }
    }
    return listRooms;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero tu respuesta puede considerarse de baja calidad. Te invito a repasar [answer]. Sería de mucha utilidad que explicaras cómo el código que has puesto de respuesta es una solución válida al problema o pregunta planteada. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu respuesta, haz clic en [edit] y agrega los detalles necesarios. Saludos